# The meaning of "oxymoronic state"

Tags: phrase-requests

Can the term "oxymoronic state" be paraphrased somehow like "a state of paradoxes?"

I know that "paradox" and "oxymoron" are completely different, and I need to translate an article for my thesis, so I need to be really sure that I understand correctly.

The context is this:

> The new Czechoslovakia was one of a number of nominally national but
>   in fact multinational states created in East Central Europe after the
>   collapse of empires in 1917-1918. In the Czechoslovak case, the
>   high-minded principle of Wilsonian self-determination combined with
>   the Realpolitik of postwar alliance politics to produce what is
>   perhaps best described as an *oxymoronic state*.

Sorry for the text being so long and thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can render *oxymoronic state* as a *state of paradoxes*, or, if you like, a *state of contradictions*. The unified country of Czechoslovakia embodied contradictions or opposites within itself, much as an [oxymoron](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/oxymoron) does.

[This article](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Czech_vs_Slovak) summarizes the differences between the Czechs and the Slovaks, and gives you an idea what an oxymoronic state it created when they were thrown together into a single country.

Comment: Well, I am actually a Czech woman and that is -maybe paradoxically- why I wasn´t sure :-) Because I would say that we differ(ed) just with the speech (and just a bit), the mentality and so on is more or less the same. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, Czechoslovakia seemed be much less of an _oxymoronic state_ than, say, the disparate entities that constituted the former Yugoslavia.